# What is this "look"? Is it an error?

Tags: grammar

**He looked a forlorn figure as he limped off.**
From Dictionary

why in this verb? Is it not look like?

Comment: If your sentence is from a dictionary, chances are very slim that it's an error. Perhaps a better question would have been, "Is this still in use?" Also, please do not say, "From Dictionary" – you really should mention which dictionary you found it in. (A shorthand note is okay, like M-W for Merriam-Webster or [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/look) for Cambridge Dictionaries Online.)

Comment: Can you please link your source (the place where you found this sentence)?

Answer (score 2):

*Look like*, the phrasal verb, has the same meaning as one of the definitions of *look*. It's just that *look like* is so common, we may come to think of it as normal or right, while using the verb *look* in the same way is so relatively uncommon that we may feel it is strange or wrong.

See sense 2, [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_enTW540TW540&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20look), and the additional example *He just didn't look himself at all.*